# How to re-enable TPM after decrypting C: drive from BitLocker?

Tags: windows-10, security, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I have a Surface Pro 6. One day my computer got locked with BitLocker (for no apparent reason). After recovering the key I disabled device encryption and decrypted my hard drive.

If I now do `manage-bde -status`, I get this information:

[image]

However, this seemed to have disabled my TPM. When I boot into UEFI, the TPM option is disabled, and when trying to enable it I get a message saying

> **The system failed to change the state of the TPM. Please reboot the system to try again.**

Disabling Secure boot does not help (I tried enabling TPM with secure boot on and off).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
TPM is also not found under **Device Manager**, as my Security Devices section does not appear even after I check "Show Hidden Devices".
[image]

I learned that this could be an issue related to BitLocker. In efforts to enable TPM, I followed instructions that told me to pause BitLocker, but that command gave me an error:

[image]

I have another surface pro that has BitLocker encryption enabled, and the TPM is enabled (as by default).

From this, I have a few questions:

- Are the issues between decrypting my drive and being unable to turn on TPM related?
- How can I re-enable my TPM module?

*For more information, I have Surface Pro 6, model 1796.

Comment: BitLocker protection is disabled on your system. So a command to suspend the protection cannot work. Your drive isn’t encrypted at all. Can you provide us the exact errors you received when you attempted to enable your TPM?

Comment: @Ramhound The error message was just a popup in UEFI, saying something like "failed to enable TPM, please restart the device and try again". There was nothing else, no error code.

Comment: Before this problem we’re you storing the BitLocker key in the TPM? I am actually looking for the exact error you received

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question with the exact message

Comment: @Ramhound Before the key was stored on my university account. I think I accidentally enabled my university account under organizations which can manage the device, and it got locked. I recovered by retrieving the key from my Microsoft account, after which I disabled BitLocker to avoid similar issues in future.

Comment: That means TPM was unlikely ever enabled, since BitLocker wasn’t using it, to store its key. According to Microsoft documentation you need to clear the TPM.  [This is safe since BitLocker protection is disabled.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-your-security-processor-tpm-firmware-94205cbc-a492-8d79-cc55-1ecd6b0a8022#:~:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Update%20%26,to%20restart%20your%20device%20to%20complete%20the%20process.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130599/discussion-between-ramhound-and-victor2748).

Comment: (1) Run `tpm.msc`. Under "Status", does it say "The TPM is ready for use"? (2) Check Windows Update for a firmware/UEFI update. If there is none, you might need to do the firmware update [manually](https://surfacetip.com/download-surface-pro-6-drivers-firmware/).

Comment: @harrymc It does not show. Even after manually updating and restarting as you mentioned. I added a screenshot of the Device manager

Comment: In the `tpm.msc` window, Action menu, do you see an entry for "Initialize TPM" or "Prepare the TPM" that is not disabled?

Comment: @harrymc No I don't, it says that compatible TPM can not be found. I have the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @Victor2748 - If you are unable to enable the TPM within the firmware settings it sounds like you are dealing with a hardware failure associated with the module itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so here’s what likely happened:

1. Your computer shipped with BitLocker enabled with a TPM-protected key
2. The TPM died
3. You had to enter the recovery key because the TPM was no longer accessible to automatically unlock the BitLocker encryption

You need to get the device repaired, there is nothing more you can do.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-book-trusted-platform-module-tpm-will-not/95187523-1c6d-465e-a5ec-e9203572b77f
https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/5fva3f/alert_bitlocker_issues_due_to_failing_tpms_in/
Others having issues with TPM on in UEFI/BIOS yet not accessible in Windows or inability to turn it off in UEFI/BIOS so this confirms it could likely be a HW fault. Hopefully OP's warranty is still active

Answer (score 1):

No, disabling bitlocker will not disable TPM. TPM is managed from the BIOS/UEFI, and bitlocker is not capable of enabling/disabling TPM.

That said, if you change secure boot options in the BIOS/UEFI, it may disable TPM.

Given that your TPM is currently disabled, it sounds like you switched to legacy mode. For TPM to be allowed, Secure Boot must also be enabled.

It may be that you must enable secure boot, reboot, enter UEFI and then be allowed to enable TPM.

Comment: OP indicated Secure Boot is/was enabled. // A TPM can be used without Secure Boot, even though they can interact.

Comment: @DanielB I've seen otherwise and OP says they have changed the secure boot setting, so better safe than sorry.

Comment: Secure boot is enabled when I initially tried it. I tried it with disabling it as well, but both failed. (It is now enabled, as it was by default)

Comment: TPM has little to do with Secure Boot.  Additionally, if Secure Boot is enabled, that means CSM must be disabled. I don’t believe SP6 devices even have CSM support. Intel certainly stopped supporting it

Comment: It does not work. I tried all possible combinations.

Answer (score -1):

All the Surface devices I have seen had TPM and were BitLocked
out of the factory.
For the Surface, this seems to a requirement imposed by
Microsoft.

The disk has not become BitLocked, but were so from the beginning.
BitLocker was most likely already installed on your Surface by
Microsoft, as most Surface devices are sold as BitLocked.
At least we can be sure that TPM was still functional up till now.

To my knowledge, TPM devices are heavily protected, hardware and
firmware, and will self-block on tampering, in effect putting
then the burden of keys-keeping on the user.
You were really lucky to be able to recover your data.

I think that when you disabled BitLocker, you have somehow
activated some anti-tamper circuits in the TPM, which caused it
to disable itself. It's possible that it became defective,
but I would assume that this is less likely to happen
spontaneously.

Since the BIOS cannot re-enable it, so Windows cannot see it,
there is nothing that you can do except firmware update,
which you tried but that did not restore the TPM functionality.

I suggest to try and get in touch with Microsoft Support, asking
for any method or software that can reset or re-initialize the TPM.
Information about it doesn't seem to be available to the public,
perhaps for a reason.

I think it's unlikely that Microsoft will release to you any
software that can reach into the TPM and modify things, except
the software that is already installed, such as `tpm.msc`.
Microsoft is much more likely to suggest sending them the Surface
to be repaired, perhaps at some cost.

**Your options for the moment seem to be, either to keep using
the Surface without TPM, or to have it repaired.**

Comment: “TPM technology is a requirement of BitLocker disk encryption” – Not it is not. The TPM is merely one possible key protector of several others.

Comment: "TPM technology is a requirement of BitLocker disk encryption," - Nope; The author could easily enable BitLocker protection with TPM provided they didn't attempt to use it and instead used a password. "I think that when you disabled BitLocker, you have activated some anti-tamper circuits in the TPM, which caused it to disable itself. " - Nope

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I meant for the Surface, but the sentence came out all wrong. I rewrote that part.

Comment: @Ramhound: How can you be so sure?

Comment: @Ramhound: Perhaps not as much as mine. So your experience says that the TPM was not designed for robustness?

Comment: @Ramhound: Surface Pro 6 was released only 3 years ago. If the TPM worked for 3 years, I don't think that it would fail suddenly. An electrical short that took it out should have caused much more damage than that. I saw an article where a member of the TPM design team discussed the enormous effort made to make the chip tamper- and fail-proof, so I think that it's more likely that the chip disabled itself, rather than a hardware problem took it out. In any case, the difference is nil: For the poster both kinds of failure are indistinguishable, so I don't really understand your insistence.

Comment: I am not the only person who disagreed with this answer. Contact them instead